# Google Translate hiding after routing to new page

Tags: typescript, angular5, google-translate

I am using Google Translate to translate my site. I am putting the dropdown on homepage and it is working just fine. However,the main issue which I am getting is that whenever I navigate to login page or any other page it gets disappeared. I have researched the console and found out that the dropdown is losing the values.

Below is my code. In my index.html I am writing this in body tag:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
      }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

and in my homepage I am writing this:

```
 <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Does my answer help? Please upvote / accept the answer if it helps because that's how the community benefits from Stackoverflow, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the Google Translate code on another page of your website, you will need to implement the same code there. The code is only on your "index.html", so I am unsure why you expect it to show up on the login page or any other page.

If I am misunderstanding your issue, please clarify with the code on your other pages (where the translation is not occurring), so I can see what's going on.